# How would a planet with extreme gravity affect a human?

Tags: gravity

I'm writing (planning really) a fantasy novel based on the fae. My "scientific" explanation for them is that the fae realm is another planet accessed via wormhole. Since I wanted them to age normally compared to humans but *seem* like ageless beings, my dad proposed that the fae planet be on the far edge of a spiral galaxy with a black hole at the centre. The centrifugal force and velocity of the system moving would mean time was slower there yes?

So we have Earth connected via wormhole to Fae, and Fae with much much stronger gravity. So I have three primary questions.

1. What adaptions would a creature born on a planet with a lot of gravity have?
2. What would the effect be for a human on Fae/a creature born on a planet with high gravity on Earth?
3. Would there be any way for a human to survive on Fae short of magic?

EDIT: Apologies for multi-question post, my bad. Since this has been answered, is it okay to just close the post?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Erin*! That's an interesting premise, but please note that we have a "One question per question post"-policy here. Could you please [edit] this post to focus on the most important question first? You can always later ask more questions in different posts and refer to this question. This might help you to incorporate the details from the first questions into later ones. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Here are a few questions you might be interested in reading: [Would the human body support living on planets with a greater gravity than Earth?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/158/28789), [How would the human body develop under a different gravity?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3781/28789),

Comment: I think you should start at the beginning and try to figure out just how much gravity you need on your planet for slowing down time sufficiently.  If you have already done such research, could you maybe include your numbers? Have you considered "advanced medicine" as an alternative solution to your aging problem?

Comment: also we advice to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer: user are all around the globe, and some of them are sleeping right now. giving them time to answer is a smart option and increases the pool of answers you get.

Comment: A tip: you should wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer. This question was posted 19 minutes(! I think that's a new record of things I've seen) before. People using WorldBuilding regularly live all around the globe and some might be discouraged when they see you already found your answer. Furthermore people might want to have a look at your question and the answers to improve the quality of both. But in the end it's your decision when to accept something and what to accept, or whether you want to accept at all. You can change the accepted answer as often as you like.

Comment: no need to delete the question: if you want you can use the edit at the bottom to modify it.

Comment: Note that "time is slower" near a gravity well is only true to observer outside the area. For those living there, time will pass "normally"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would the human body develop under a different gravity?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3781/how-would-the-human-body-develop-under-a-different-gravity)

Comment: I would like to add that just because a planet orbits a black hole does not mean that planet has higher gravity. If the sun were to all of a suddenly turn into a black hole, our orbit would not change, even though the sun would become smaller than the earth. A planet has higher or lower gravity depending on its mass. I'm not sure what you're talking about when you say centrifugal force. That really isn't a term you should toss around in a physics class because it requires a reference frame other than the universe itself. Your planet would have high gravity if it were really big.

Answer (score 2):

There is a computer game called *Mass Effect*. In the game there are alien species and one of them is called *Elcor*.

Elcor come from a high gravity planet like you explained and they evolved that way.  They have rough skin, they move very slowly , they are very strong etc.

One of the things I find interesting about Elcor is: They have under developed facial muscles because most of the energy has to be spend against gravity , so they can’t do mimics and when they talk to humans , they verbally state their emotion by saying things like *laughing, angry,sad* after finishing a sentence.

[Here is the link to Elcor Wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Elcor)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. These creatures will be considerably shorter and stockier than humans. They will need thick, powerful bones and a strong heart and circulatory system. This will prevent gravity from simply pooling blood in the feet. Something else to note is that is will be highly unlikely for animals with exoskeletons to exist, as they'd be crushed under their own weight.

2.1. Without a pressure suit (similar to what pilots wear), humans might be crushed, die due to the aforementioned gravity issues and would generally have a hard time, due to the fundamentally different circumstances.

2.2 Astronauts suffer some serious ill effects due to micro gravity in space. Your Fae might have a similar response to the new environment

3. As I mentioned, they would need dedicated pressure suits and (if the gravity makes movement sluggish) some kind of exoskeleton.

Just to add to your scientific principles, the center of the galaxy is incredibly violent. Black holes give off more power through radiation in seconds, than our sun will in its lifetime. Also, You'd need specialized ships to travel worm holes, since they tend to be fairly violent to whatever tries to travel through

Comment: -1 for a "pressure suit" helping with high gravity. They help with air pressure for breathing. You're probably confusing them with G-suits, which pilots wear to keep blood from pooling in their legs and causing blackouts during aggressive maneuvering. It's an effect of angular acceleration, not gravity as experienced by people walking around.